# Converting double to int or even decimal place

Tags: java

I was wondering if someone could tell me 
1. why, when i input weightNumber with a decimal place, weightConverted doesn't convert it to the whole number, even though I create variable for it?
2. how could i improve this "program" in any way, THANK YOU !!

***here is the problem:***

[image]

**code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class cofee {

    public static void main (String []args){


        double weightNumber = 0;
        String packageType = "";
        String serviceType ="";
        double totalFee = 0;
        double weightConverted = Math.round(weightNumber); // <- this is the problem, should i put it somewhere else?

        final double LETTERCOSTP = 12.00;
        final double LETTERCOSTS = 10.50;
        final double BOXCOSTP = 15.75;
        final double BOXCOSTS = 13.75;
        final double BOXWEIGHTP = 1.25;
        final double BOXWEIGHTS = 1.00;

        // input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter package type (letter/box): ");
            packageType = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        System.out.print("Enter type of service (standard/priority): ");
            serviceType = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        switch(packageType)
        {
        case "letter":
            System.out.print("Enter the weight in ounces: ");
            weightNumber = input.nextDouble();
            break;

        case "box":
            System.out.print("Enter the weight in pounds: ");
            weightNumber = input.nextDouble();
            break;

            default:
                System.out.print("WRONG PACKAGE TYPE !!!");
        }



            // letter
        if (packageType.equals("letter") && serviceType.equals("priority"))
        {
            totalFee = LETTERCOSTP;
        }
        if (packageType.equals("letter") && serviceType.equals("standard"))
        {
            totalFee = LETTERCOSTS;
        }


            // box
        if (packageType.equals("box") && serviceType.equals("priority"))
        {
            totalFee = BOXCOSTP + ((weightConverted - 1.0) * BOXWEIGHTP);
        }
        if (packageType.equals("box") && serviceType.equals("standard"))
        {
            totalFee = BOXCOSTS + ((weightConverted - 1.0) * BOXWEIGHTS);
        }





        // display

        System.out.println("The fee is € "+ totalFee + " for a package with");
        System.out.println("\tType: "+packageType);
        System.out.println("\tService: "+serviceType);
        System.out.println("\tOunces: "+weightConverted);




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `double weightConverted = Math.round(weightNumber);` will call `round()` with the value of `weightNumber`, **which is `0`**, so it rounds `0` to... well... `0`, and assigns it to `weightConverted`.

Comment: And you do, down where you call `nextDouble()`, but that won't change the value of `weightConverted`.